# Integral of funcion $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)>0, \, \forall x \in [0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

$f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ bounded and $f(x)>0, \, \forall x \in [0,1]$

1. Prove that exists $c>0$ such that $X_c=\{ x \in [0,1] \mid f(x)\geq c\}$ has nonzero measure.
2. Prove that
   $$ \displaystyle \int_{\_0}^{1}f(x) \, dx>0$$
   (here $\int_{\_0}^{1}f(x) \, dx$ is the lower sum of $f$ in $[0,1]$, in the Riemann sense)

I started to prove that, if not exists $c>0$ such that $X_c$ has nonzero measure then for every $\frac{1}{n} \in \mathbb{R}$ with $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $C(X_{1/n})=0$ ($C(X)=\text{measure of }X$), then $C\left( \displaystyle \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} X_{1/n}\right)=0 \Rightarrow  C([0,1])=0$ ( is that right?). For item 2, I have no idea, I think it might be delimiting, but I can not get the strict inequality

Comment: Your first part is good. For the second question, you can cut the integral in two : $X_c$ and his complementary. On the complementary, the integral is positive or zero, and on $X_c$, the integral is greater than $c\times m(X_c)>0$

Comment: but I'm just working with the integral of Riemann, I'm not sure you can separate the integral that way

Comment: Indeed... then I think there may be a problem. Take a countable number of disjoints copy of $\mathbb{Q}$, and call them $Q_1, \cdots, Q_n, \cdots $. Now define a function f such that : $$\left\lbrace \begin{array} .f(x) = \frac{1}{n} & \text{if} & x\in Q_n \\ f(x) = 1 & & \text{elsewhere} \end{array} \right.$$ By density of each of the $Q_n$, the lower sum is zero. The integral is then 0.

Answer (score 0):

Let be P([0,1]) a partition of that interval, then we'll define $$ \int_{\_0}^{1}f(x)dx = sup\{L(f;p)\}$$, where p belongs to P([0,1])} ,
On the other hand 
$$ L(f;p)=\sum_{i=1}^n m_i(x_i-x_{i-1})$$, where $$m_i=inf{\{f(x),x belongs [x_{i-1}-x_{i}]}\}$$

Now take a look of our hypothesis, which establishes that f(x)>0, so f(x)>0 in each sub interval of [0,1] then$$inf{\{f(x),xbelongs [x_{i-1}-x_{i}]}\}>0$$ for all i=1...n,

so we find that $m_i$>0, it follows $L(f;p)>0$, thus $sup\{L(f;p)\}>0$
Finally we get that  $$ \int_{\_0}^{1}f(x)dx >0$$